# How to convert a PDF file to an AI file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, pdf

I have a logo that I want to convert from pdf to ai, but I don't know how to convert it and whether doing so will damage the logo quality.

can you help me please?

Comment: You can open the PDF from Illustrator, but keep in mind that just because you save it as an .ai file that doesn't mean you are converting it to vector quality art. If it's a photo/scan/rasterized image, it will still stay that way. Perhaps you're looking to "trace" the image and convert it to vector art? That's different.

Answer (score 2):

Just open the PDF file in Adobe Illustrator.

> Import an Adobe PDF file In Illustrator, choose File > Open.
>
> - In the Open dialog box, select the PDF file, and click Open.

Comment: I want to convert the file to ai not just open it.

Comment: Open it and save it as an Adobe Illustrator file